# How do I use FOP with Spring Boot without any Exceptions while starting the app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-fop

I have a problem while creating PDF from XML in Java with Apach FOP.

I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException when Spring loads the context (by Start):

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

2019-12-06 15:08:26.995  INFO 8744 --- [           main] d.a.s.RestserviceVonKundeApplication     : Starting RestserviceVonKundeApplication on DESKTOP-JJCROQS with PID 8744 (D:\Workspace\ikar\build\classes\java\main started by annpo in D:\Workspace\ikar)
2019-12-06 15:08:26.997  INFO 8744 --- [           main] d.a.s.RestserviceVonKundeApplication     : No ....
....
....
2019-12-06 15:08:28.487  WARN 8744 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/annpo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/d55d3f02a56ec4c25695fe67e1334ff8c2ecea23/xercesImpl.jar] from classloader hierarchy

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\annpo\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\d55d3f02a56ec4c25695fe67e1334ff8c2ecea23\xercesImpl.jar (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-

2019-12-06 15:08:28.488  WARN 8744 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/annpo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/d55d3f02a56ec4c25695fe67e1334ff8c2ecea23/xml-apis.jar] from classloader hierarchy

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\annpo\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\d55d3f02a56ec4c25695fe67e1334ff8c2ecea23\xml-apis.jar (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
............
.................
..................
2019-12-06 15:08:28.489  WARN 8744 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/annpo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/d55d3f02a56ec4c25695fe67e1334ff8c2ecea23/serializer.jar] from classloader hierarchy

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\annpo\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\d55d3f02a56ec4c25695fe67e1334ff8c2ecea23\serializer.jar (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]

...................
....................
.................
```

My the whole Gradle file looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'de.anna.springboot.ikar'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper"
    compile "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"
    compile "com.h2database:h2"
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    compile "org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:3.0.8"
    compile "org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:3.0.8"
    compile "org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:3.0.8"
    compile "org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:3.0.8"
    compile "org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:1.0.6"
    compile "org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:2.3"
    compile "junit:junit:4.12"
    compile "org.wiztools:xsd-gen:0.2.1"
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.10'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

What do I do wrong?
Maybe should I use another Library to create PDF.
I presume something is not correct with gradle dependences.

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t done anything wrong. You have a jar (from Xalan) on the classpath with a `Class-Path` entry in the manifest that points to some jars that does not exist. Arguably, it is this jar that is wrong.

Tomcat is attempting to find JSP tag library definitions (TLDs) when you start your application. It is warning you that it has been unable to find some jars so has been unable to scan them.

The warnings are benign so you could chose to ignore them. That’s probably not very satisfying though.

Alternatively, you could configure Tomcat’s TLD scanning to skip the jar with the faulty manifest. In Spring Boot you can configure this using the `server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns` property:

> Comma-separated list of additional patterns that match jars to ignore for TLD scanning. The special '?' and '*' characters can be used in the pattern to match one and only one character and zero or more characters respectively.

The value should be something like `xalan-*.jar`